# Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая и где именно?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

На загоревшую от долгого нахождения в поле руку опустился ярко-оранжевый листок.

Answer (score 2):

Причастный оборот не выделяется запятой, если стоит перед определяемым существительным.
В этом предложении запятые не нужны, поскольку причастие "загоревшую" расположено перед определяемым существительным "руку".